# How to sort descending order in smartGWT using FormItem class

Tags: java, smartgwt

I am getting through a map the desc sorted order ,but when i am setting in form item class it is still showing asc order.

```
formItem.setValueMap(StaticValueMapProvider.getCIDRValueMap(ipFormatSelected, objectTypeInContext));
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: formItem.setValueMap(StaticValueMapProvider.getCIDRValueMap(ipFormatSelected, objectTypeInContext));

Comment: @Clarity can you look into this ?